# Nginx behind Istio Service Mesh

Tags: nginx, istio

I have k8 setup with one master and two worker node and deployed micro services and front-end i used Nginx as a reverse proxy to transfer incoming request to the backed services.

Now the question is can we implement the istio service mesh or  this will make any issue existing? nginx reverse proxy

Please find the sample reverse proxy code

```
server {
  server_name app1.local;

  location ~ {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3300;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {
  server_name app2.local;

  location ~ {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off; 
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Now the question is if i want to implement istio, Configure an ingress gateway to re-direct the traffic to backend micro services, how i can do that?

Comment: Have you tried to configure that and verify if it works? In my opinion it should work, but i'm not sure about how mtls would work here. When the request would go from ingress to nginx it would be encrypted, but then it might be not encrypted when doing the reverse proxy to your backend. Also worth to note that [Envoy requires HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 traffic for upstream services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#envoy-won-t-connect-to-my-http-1-0-service).

Comment: Hi Jakub, i have not tried yet there is requirement from the project to add istio

Comment: why would you still use nginx ?

Comment: HI Peter, this my question, if i use istio, nginx is whether is required or not, because i need i am using nginx as reverse proxy to route the traffic to backend micro services